# RTX Quadro 4000 vs RTX 2080

Tags: rendering, gpu, performance, hardware

I`m from Russia so sorry for my English.

I have to plan to start learn blender (sculpting and making short cartoons 5 min max)
Now I have 8700K + 32 RAM + RTX 2080

Do be better to change GPU to RTX Quadro 4000 or Blender more prefer gaming GPU for viewport, real time rotation and fast final render.

Maybe be better change CPU to AMD like 2600X?

Comment: Unless you change your hardware to HEDT platform, I don't think there will be a noticeable performance different between 8700K and 2600x(or even 3950x) also RTX 2080 and Quadro 4000. If you really though Blender is kind of laggy on doing every thing, you should **consider using other commercial software** like Maya or Z Brush in your case.

Comment: And I would assume that sculpting in Blender doesn't support muti-thread, so changing it from 8700K to AMD will probably slower the process since the frequency is normally lower in AMD processor.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Hardware recommendations are off topic here, try asking over at https://blenderartists.org

Comment: Ray Mairlot thnx As I understood more prefer to hava a fast GPU and Intel =)

Answer (score 1):

Go to https://opendata.blender.org/

> Blender Benchmark platform collect and display the results of hardware and software performance tests

[image]

You can search by gpu/cpu names in this site and view the results: https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/query/

Comment: jailton_so - Thnx for ur answer I showed ur link and have a question here is my screenshot - https://i.imgur.com/Wjz6LnO.jpg 

If i correct understood 2070 super and 2080 - about the same result in speed But U showed me pic with CPU and GPU and It§s mean that GPU more faster in Blender than CPU in the same task?

And I see that Quadro 4000 not fast than 2080 but cost more =)

Comment: For render, gpu generally has advantages over cpu. First, the 2070 super may have been overclocked to get close to 2080. Second, gpu can have better results because they have more cores working in parallel and the gpu has VRAM, which is much faster than RAM (blender must have a good support for use that and, out of curiosity, in this Linus test, blender cannot use all 128 threads of the AMD Epyc CPU [video](https://youtu.be/HuLsrr79-Pw?t=510).

Comment: About the Quadro and RTX gpu's comparison, Quadro has more memory (with ECC -> error correction memory), offers more video connections, has video utilities like Mosaic and Quadro Sync... see this video where Linus explains why he uses a Quadro GAMING at 16K RESOLUTION and this [link](
https://www.engineering.com/DesignSoftware/DesignSoftwareArticles/ArticleID/18630/%20What%20is%20the%20difference%20between%20GeForce%20and%20Quadro-Graphics-Cards) for crazy details hahauauh. In some scenarios a Quadro GPU is more effective 

Comment: jailton_so wow thnx for big feedback and U pushed me dawn I more confused between RTX 4000 and RTX 2080 ok I ask question from other side - Does the Quadro better for Blender if we have to chose RTX 2070 Super or RTX 4000? (I have also PNY Quadro P600 and Use it for 10-bit in Photoshop but also tested in The Wither 3: Wild Hund and in low setting got playable FPS ) and Does the Blender have features for Quadro?

Comment: looking for that, I don't find any blender features specifically for Quadro cards, just mainstream software like Solidworks (CAD), Vray (render), etc. seem to have that support. And the only benefit I found is that Quadro cards have more Vram to work on really big scenes that demands a huge amount of memory to run. That's all I know so far, and for more details I think it's best to try contact nvidia support [link](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/support/)

Comment: jailton_so thx again and I think that i have last answer as I saw this site (opendata) RX 5700XT to close to 2080 ti in render time but cost low. And see also RADEON VII - and time is very bad. Now I think about RX 5700X. What do think?

Comment: yeah, its a good choice! I never tests any highend pieces of hardware, it's hard to say precisely which one to choose. For me, I would go with the cheapest :') but you must take into account that Nvidia cards have more support in this industry, see CUDA and Optix technologies for example. Conclusion: RX 5700 offer a really good results and good price over RTX 2080 ti and, if those results are enough for you, go with RX 5700. Otherwise, if money is not problem, go with 2080 ti

Comment: and check more benchmarks to have sure about performance